# If $f$ is differentiable at $c$, how do I prove that...

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, derivatives

If $f$ is differentiable at $c$, how do I prove that

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c + \alpha h) - f(c - \beta h)}{h} = (\alpha + \beta)f'(c)
$$

Comment: There is a typo. You want $h\to 0$.

Comment: Where is $x$ in the function?

Comment: $h$ should go to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

1.
$$\frac{A-B}{h}=\frac{A-C+C-B}{h}=\frac{A-C}{h}+\frac{C-B}{h}$$

2. $$\frac{A-C}{h} = \frac{a(A-C)}{ah}$$

(Special treatment is needed to the cases $\alpha =0$ and $\beta=0$)

Answer (score 0):

$$\alpha\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(c+\alpha h)-f(c)}{\alpha h}-(-\beta)\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(c-\beta h)-f(c)}{-\beta h}$$

Comment: It is important to remark that both limits exist (by assuming $f$ is differentiable at $c$).

Comment: @NiklasHebestreit, " $f$  is differentiable at $c$"

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c + \alpha h) - f(c - \beta h)}{h} &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c + \alpha h) - f(c - \beta h) + f(c) - f(c)}{h} \\
&= \alpha\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c + \alpha h) - f(c)}{\alpha h} + \beta\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c) - f(c - \beta h)}{\beta h} \\
&= (\alpha + \beta)f'(c)
\end{align}